# FitNesse: How to correctly configure XmlHttpTest to read web service results

Tags: fitnesse

I've been trying to configure [XmlHttpTest](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) in FitNesse to create a basic SOAP web service test.

I just can't quite seem to nail down the required syntax/config for the test.

My test page looks like this:

```
!path fixtures
!path fixtures/*.jar

!define slim.port {0}
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!define URL {http://localhost:55088/GetEmployee.asmx}

!define POST_BODY_4 { {{{
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s11:Body>
    <ns1:GetEmployees xmlns:ns1="http://someorg.co.uk/">
    </ns1:GetEmployees>
  </s11:Body>
</s11:Envelope>
}}} }

|Import|
|nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture|
|nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim|

|script|xml http test|

|table template |send request                                  |
|post           |${POST_BODY_4} |to           |${URL}          |
|check          |response status|200                           |
|show           |response                                      |
|$Name=         |xPath          |//Employee[1]/FirstName/text()|

|send request|
|Name?       |
|Fred        |
```

The web service method returns the following (visible in the `show response`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetEmployeesResponse xmlns="http://someorg.co.uk/">
            <GetEmployeesResult>
                <Employee>
                    <FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Bloggs</LastName>
                    <id>123</id>
                    <FacilityName>London</FacilityName>
                </Employee>
            </GetEmployeesResult>
        </GetEmployeesResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My test fails (null is the actual result). I guess I'm getting the `xPath` part wrong but I'm not sure why. There is no namespace prefix so I guess I don't need to use `register prefix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a namespace for `http://someorg.co.uk/` the fact that the response uses it as default for all elements below `GetEmployeesResponse` does not change the fact that it is present.

Assuming you register an 'a' namespace for 'http://someorg.co.uk/' your xPath becomes: `//a:Employee[1]/a:FirstName/text()` (and since there is only one Employee, and no other children of FirstName, you could also write `//a:Employee/a:FirstName`

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Fried, for helping out a complete novice!